# AWS : Cannot add new listener to an existing load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, aws-auto-scaling

It seems like we cannot more than one `listener` et an AWS Network Load Balancer.

I've a Load balancer already listening for HTTPS/TLS on port 443. As my instances behind also support `http` some vhost, I would like to add new HTTP/80 listener to the load balancer, but when I try, I can available target groups depending on protocol (TCP, or HTTP), but one I select the target of the listener, the `add` button remains grey, so I can't add neither a new HTTP listener nor a TCP listener to my load balancer.

It's been a while that I didn't build on AWS, did I miss something?

[image]

[image]

Comment: They can't be on the same ports.

Comment: Yes. you have to delete existing port listener and add new or use different port